# Compressed backups with daterolling file appender in log4js with node

Tags: log4js-node

I am new to nodejs and I am trying to compress the backup log files with DateRolling File appended using log4js with nodejs.
  "appenders": [
                {
                  "type":       "dateFile",
                  "pattern":"_yyyy_MM_dd.zip",
                   alwaysIncludePattern":false,
                  }
I am getting zip files but they are not actually compressed.

Answer (score 0):

ok..so i found the solution for this. Look like in the new implementation of log4js (version 1.0.0) they have compression feature included.

https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/pull/171

Comment: log4js.configure({
  "appenders": [ {
    "type": "dateFile",
    "filename": "blah.log",
    "pattern": "-yyyy-MM-dd",
    "alwaysIncludePattern": false,
    "compress": true // new option
  } ]
});